# Кодировка и формат XML записанного функцией COPY

Tags: postgresql

Проблема в следующем. Код записи таблицы в файл в мой процедуре такой:

```
copy (select table_to_xml('a', true, true, '')) to'D:\\TestTask\\PersonsForm\\use.xml';
```

Но xml-файл получается такой:

```
\n\n 2\n Houston\n Whitney\n Father\n \n \n \n \n\n\n
```

Во-первых все на одной строчке. Еще пока незнаю, насколько это критично, но все же как сделать нормальный формат? Во-вторых, ни браузер, ни ява-программа его не открывают из-за символов nn в двух местах в файле. В-третьих, если до COPY файл был формата UTF-8, то после COPY кодировка файла = ANSI. Как убрать это преобразование? Если их убрать вручную, то браузер выводит:

```
2\n Houston\n Whitney\n Father\n \n \n \n \n
```

Пробовала ставить `DELIMITER "\n"`, но при компиляции процедуры выпадает ошибка:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ""\n""LINE 40: DELIMITER "\n"     ^
```

Что делать? Как это решить? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

по поводу кодировки - используйте параметр encoding команды COPY

```
copy (select table_to_xml('a', true, true, '')) to'D:\\TestTask\\PersonsForm\\use.xml' with encoding 'utf8';
```